# C# - cannot implicitly convert type 'string[][]' to 'int[][]'

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, cpu-usage

I am trying to write a script in C# to calculate the CPU usage of a server. For that, I am using 'cat /proc/stat' and then I am following this guide: [how to calculate CPU usage](https://github.com/Leo-G/DevopsWiki/wiki/How-Linux-CPU-Usage-Time-and-Percentage-is-calculated).

First I need to find out the `cpu_total_time` and the `cpu_idle_time` and then calculate the

```
cpu_usage_time = (cpu_total_time - cpu_idle_time) / cpu_total_time * delta
```

where delta is the difference between the readings contained in the `cpu_old` and `cpu_new` in seconds.

My script so far is:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        float delta = 300;
        string cpu_old = @"cpu  434473062 3549 100174857 65243175066 2350230 0 23538998 0 0 0
cpu0 40363141 158 9961795 4046071159 14998 0 2151386 0 0 0
cpu1 43114169 130 9906697 4044059231 14821 0 2322581 0 0 0
cpu2 46217091 118 10451188 4043699342 14271 0 2530557 0 0 0
cpu3 46520571 95 10394572 4046346748 12427 0 2533812 0 0 0
cpu4 44400015 73 9822374 4051834091 8572 0 2383614 0 0 0
cpu5 41373066 95 9107815 4057879672 9063 0 2207833 0 0 0
cpu6 40070307 94 8892688 4060344982 15899 0 2174872 0 0 0
cpu7 39194082 109 8715754 4062643570 14710 0 2110436 0 0 0
cpu8 14996205 327 3564661 4099822309 14742 0 840150 0 0 0
cpu9 12736725 346 3132467 4102694576 12765 0 715207 0 0 0
cpu10 10787760 349 2569831 4105053050 11834 0 587924 0 0 0
cpu11 10278285 269 2568664 4105585391 5650 0 550660 0 0 0
cpu12 9466026 331 2448787 4104518475 2159416 0 514311 0 0 0
cpu13 9650748 328 2437976 4106764105 10611 0 516373 0 0 0
cpu14 10903552 332 2733229 4105176301 12290 0 600582 0 0 0
cpu15 14401310 386 3466350 4100682055 18153 0 798693 0 0 0";
        // Counting the number of lines the cpu_old variable has (number of CPU cores)
        int numLines = cpu_old.Split('\n').Length;
        // Creating a 2-D array from the input string
        var cpu_usage_old =  cpu_old.Split('\n').Select(x => x.Replace("cpu ","").Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
        string cpu_new = @"cpu  434474592 3549 100175256 65244055979 2350259 0 23539065 0 0 0
cpu0 40363255 158 9961820 4046126195 14998 0 2151391 0 0 0
cpu1 43114268 130 9906722 4044114283 14821 0 2322584 0 0 0
cpu2 46217222 118 10451220 4043754354 14271 0 2530564 0 0 0
cpu3 46520645 95 10394592 4046401839 12427 0 2533813 0 0 0
cpu4 44400082 73 9822391 4051889189 8572 0 2383616 0 0 0
cpu5 41373168 95 9107845 4057934721 9063 0 2207838 0 0 0
cpu6 40070438 94 8892720 4060399997 15899 0 2174878 0 0 0
cpu7 39194253 109 8715790 4062698541 14710 0 2110444 0 0 0
cpu8 14996240 327 3564671 4099877456 14742 0 840151 0 0 0
cpu9 12737022 346 3132532 4102749364 12765 0 715223 0 0 0
cpu10 10787804 349 2569845 4105108184 11834 0 587924 0 0 0
cpu11 10278327 269 2568684 4105640505 5650 0 550661 0 0 0
cpu12 9466052 331 2448797 4104573595 2159444 0 514312 0 0 0
cpu13 9650910 328 2438016 4106819087 10611 0 516382 0 0 0
cpu14 10903566 332 2733236 4105231472 12290 0 600582 0 0 0
cpu15 14401335 386 3466367 4100737188 18153 0 798694 0 0 0";
        var cpu_usage_new = cpu_new.Split('\n').Select(x => x.Replace("cpu ","").Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
        var cpuUsage = new List<int>();
        foreach (var idx in Enumerable.Range(0, numLines))
        {       
              int cpu_time_old = cpu_usage_old[idx, 0] + cpu_usage_old[idx][1] + cpu_usage_old[idx][2] + cpu_usage_old[idx][3] + cpu_usage_old[idx][4] + cpu_usage_old[idx][5] + cpu_usage_old[idx][6] + cpu_usage_old[idx][7];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have just tried to calculate the `cpu_usage_old` here but the rest would be more or less straight-forward. 
I see two possible solutions to my problem:

1. Convert all the elements of the 2D arrays `cpu_usage_new` and `cpu_usage_old` into integers at the time of creation and then working with the columns of the matrix, instead of running a for loop. And then add the value to a new column of the same 2D array.
2. Convert the elements at the time of summing/subtracting within the for loop but this will be a long and not so elegant way to deal with the problem. I can then append all the results into the `cpuUsage` list where each value will be the CPU usage of this particular CPU core for the specified `delta` period of time.

Comment: well, that code doesn't compile because of the dimensionality error on `cpu_usage_old[idx, 0]`, but ultimately I guess you're looking for `int.Parse`?

Comment: There are more errors than that, you have an error in your LINQ query, when you want to replace the string cpu for the empty string, but you have cpu0 and cpu1 and so on, so those strings won't get replaced.

Comment: Also, you can't index `cpu_usage_old[idx][0]` because that's not a number, it's `cpu0` and `cpu1`, etc when `idx > 0`

Comment: The `Select(x => x.Replace("cpu ","")` line is actually removing the `cpu`, `cpu0`, etc. from the 2-D array. So my `cpu_usage_old` has only numbers formatted as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the corrected version of the code you posted. Hopefully it will allow you to complete your task.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        float delta = 300;
        string cpu_old = @"cpu  434473062 3549 100174857 65243175066 2350230 0 23538998 0 0 0
cpu0 40363141 158 9961795 4046071159 14998 0 2151386 0 0 0
cpu1 43114169 130 9906697 4044059231 14821 0 2322581 0 0 0
cpu2 46217091 118 10451188 4043699342 14271 0 2530557 0 0 0
cpu3 46520571 95 10394572 4046346748 12427 0 2533812 0 0 0
cpu4 44400015 73 9822374 4051834091 8572 0 2383614 0 0 0
cpu5 41373066 95 9107815 4057879672 9063 0 2207833 0 0 0
cpu6 40070307 94 8892688 4060344982 15899 0 2174872 0 0 0
cpu7 39194082 109 8715754 4062643570 14710 0 2110436 0 0 0
cpu8 14996205 327 3564661 4099822309 14742 0 840150 0 0 0
cpu9 12736725 346 3132467 4102694576 12765 0 715207 0 0 0
cpu10 10787760 349 2569831 4105053050 11834 0 587924 0 0 0
cpu11 10278285 269 2568664 4105585391 5650 0 550660 0 0 0
cpu12 9466026 331 2448787 4104518475 2159416 0 514311 0 0 0
cpu13 9650748 328 2437976 4106764105 10611 0 516373 0 0 0
cpu14 10903552 332 2733229 4105176301 12290 0 600582 0 0 0
cpu15 14401310 386 3466350 4100682055 18153 0 798693 0 0 0";
        // Counting the number of lines the cpu_old variable has (number of CPU cores)
        int numLines = cpu_old.Split('\n').Length;

        // Creating a 2-D array from the input string
        var cpu_usage_old =  cpu_old.Split('\n').Select(x => x.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();

        string cpu_new = @"cpu  434474592 3549 100175256 65244055979 2350259 0 23539065 0 0 0
cpu0 40363255 158 9961820 4046126195 14998 0 2151391 0 0 0
cpu1 43114268 130 9906722 4044114283 14821 0 2322584 0 0 0
cpu2 46217222 118 10451220 4043754354 14271 0 2530564 0 0 0
cpu3 46520645 95 10394592 4046401839 12427 0 2533813 0 0 0
cpu4 44400082 73 9822391 4051889189 8572 0 2383616 0 0 0
cpu5 41373168 95 9107845 4057934721 9063 0 2207838 0 0 0
cpu6 40070438 94 8892720 4060399997 15899 0 2174878 0 0 0
cpu7 39194253 109 8715790 4062698541 14710 0 2110444 0 0 0
cpu8 14996240 327 3564671 4099877456 14742 0 840151 0 0 0
cpu9 12737022 346 3132532 4102749364 12765 0 715223 0 0 0
cpu10 10787804 349 2569845 4105108184 11834 0 587924 0 0 0
cpu11 10278327 269 2568684 4105640505 5650 0 550661 0 0 0
cpu12 9466052 331 2448797 4104573595 2159444 0 514312 0 0 0
cpu13 9650910 328 2438016 4106819087 10611 0 516382 0 0 0
cpu14 10903566 332 2733236 4105231472 12290 0 600582 0 0 0
cpu15 14401335 386 3466367 4100737188 18153 0 798694 0 0 0";
        var cpu_usage_new = cpu_new.Split('\n').Select(x => x.Replace("cpu ","").Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
        var cpuUsage = new List<int>();
        foreach (var idx in Enumerable.Range(0, numLines))
        {       
              long cpu_time_old = Convert.ToInt64(cpu_usage_old[idx][1],10) + Convert.ToInt64(cpu_usage_old[idx][2],10) + Convert.ToInt64(cpu_usage_old[idx][3],10) + Convert.ToInt64(cpu_usage_old[idx][4],10) + Convert.ToInt64(cpu_usage_old[idx][5],10) + Convert.ToInt64(cpu_usage_old[idx][6],10) + Convert.ToInt64(cpu_usage_old[idx][7],10) + Convert.ToInt64(cpu_usage_old[idx][8],10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's polite to explain why an answer get's downvoted. It also helps with writing better answers next time. I certainly have a doubt about why it was downvoted because it fixed the errors.

Comment: One possibility could be that the answer doesn't appear to provide any information about what the problem was, what changes were made, and how those changes correct the problem.  The Stack Overflow community strives to *not* be simply a "free coding service", and answers which provide code to be copied/pasted with no explanation of the solution (essentially no answer to the question) tend to disserve that goal.